# How can a specific model be cleared from the memory?

Tags: python, keras

I created several Keras models (`Model_1, Model_2...Model_N`) in one code. I would like to clear only one specified model (e.g. `Model_1`).

I guess `K.clear_session()`, which will clear all models from the memory, is not useful in this case. Is there any solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Some hints here [How could I release gpu memory of keras](http://forums.fast.ai/t/how-could-i-release-gpu-memory-of-keras/2023)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `del[]` to explicitly delete the variables you no longer need, this triggers python's garbage collector. so put all the variables associated with that model inside `del[]` and python would free the memory.

Comment: Please be more specific; it is unclear what the brackets mean. Do you mean it should be `del[Model_1]` (I doubt it...)?

Comment: @desertnaut every variable that is associated with the model should go inside the brackets separated by a `,`